# How to automatically enable a button

Tags: html, jsp

I have a button in a JSP which gets disabled after the first click. This is just to prevent multiple form submission at the same time. I want to enable the button once the form is submitted. My current logic keeps the button enabled and it seems like it bypass the disable property.

Without `this.disabled = false` button works perfectly fine by keeping the button disabled but I also want it to be enabled once the process is finished.

```
<input type="submit" class="esignReports" value="Export E-Sign Information"  title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please wait...';document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit();this.disabled = false">
```

Is there anyway to do it without `JS`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think your button actually gets disabled but it gets re-enabled automatically because the submit is async, so you don't have enough time to see it's 'disabled' state. You could put console.log(this.state) before and after the submit() call to be sure.

There's no way to get a callback on submit() calls using plain Javascript (since it is supposed to send the info and reload the page). You'll need to use jQuery if you want to re-enable the button, using callbacks.

Comment: You are right Maxime. I don't see the disable part at all as you mentioned I don't get enough time. Let me try JQuery. Thanks for the confirmation though.